# Riemann-Hurwitz Formula Using Homology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Does someone know of any good reference for a proof of the Riemann-Hurwitz Formula (of Riemann Surfaces) that uses Spectral-Sequences and Homology ?

Thanks in advance !

[ I think I know how to start this kind of proof, but have no idea on how to finish it...If no one has a good reference, I might ask for the specialists' help in finishing my idea]

Comment: Why do you want this?  Riemann-Hurwitz is already quite easy to prove using the local model theorem.  Presumably you're thinking of the Serre spectral sequence, for which you need a fibration, for which you'd need to punch out the ramification points, to do which you need the local model theorem in the first place (and then you're basically done anyways).  What's the beginning of your proof?

Comment: You can find the same question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99292/question-regarding-riemann-hurwitz-formula-proof